# get last value from GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

i have table like

```
id  Name       Taste      price        Qty
1   Hot-Dog    Spicy      500           3
2   Pop-Corn   Caramel    400           2
3   Hot-Dog    Non-Spicy  600           1      
4   Hot-Dog    Spicy      520           4     
5   Pop-Corn   Salty      350           5
```

how to make a return row

```
Name       Taste      price    Qty
Hot-Dog    Spicy      520       7  <--- Group by name and taste, sum(qty), with lastest price 
Pop-Corn   Caramel    400       2
Hot-Dog    Non-Spicy  600       1
Pop-Corn   Salty      350       5

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *,sum(qty) as qtys FROM sometable GROUP BY name,taste");
```

simply word.. return group by name and taste with "lastest price(biggest id) from same item" and sum(qty)

how to get lastest price. i try min(),max() it return smallest or biggest value.

Comment: "Latest" doesn't mean anything - do you mean the one with the biggest ID?

Comment: yeah biggest id. last inserted to database.( for same name and taste).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you're allowed to refer to columns that aren't in the GROUP BY clause or inside an aggregate function, however as per the docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html the resulting value returned is indeterminate if they aren't all the same.

However, you can do the query in two steps: first, get the aggregate information, then join it back to the same table to get the price of the max id:

```
SELECT name, taste, price, qtys
FROM (SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid, SUM(qty) AS qtys FROM sometable GROUP BY name, taste) AS lnt
JOIN sometable AS st ON st.id = lnt.maxid
ORDER BY name, taste
```

Explanation of how this works:

Start with the inner query. In here, we're grouping the data by name and taste, and then getting the sum of quantities for each (name, taste) pair, and the max id (which was your "latest" entry you were after). We could also get the actual name and the taste values if we wanted to from here, but there's no point because we can get that later from the outer table (the max id is all the info we need to get the name and taste) and it simplifies the SQL a little.

Now the inner query will give you a list of unique ids and quantities. Each ID references a (name, taste) pair - specifically, the one with the largest ID for that (name, taste) combination. So, we join the inner query back to the sometable table, matching the maxid to the id fields.

Then it's just a simple matter of returning the name, taste, and price from sometable, and the qtys from the inner table, and you have everything you need - name, taste, "latest" price, and the sum of quantities.

Comment: i'll try apply this code. ill give you feedback later

Comment: jon thanks, it is work, from my newbie eyes.. it work something like first we pick all name and taste from sometable, and replace qty with sum(qty) or qtys, am i right?

Comment: Yep, since there's no way to say "get me the price that corresponds to the max id" we go "okay, get me the max id, and then i'll join that back to the table to get the price". I used to do basically just this query on some computer availability data I had a few years back, so I feel your pain :)

Comment: Oh, and yeah, the quantity we also grab while we're getting the max id, since we're putting all the aggregate stuff inside the inner query, and then we grab the name and taste and price from the outer query. We could use the name and taste from the inner query instead if we want. They're the same values either way, since the ID matches inside to outside.

Comment: Actually I'll edit the answer so it explains the process a little better.

Comment: many thanks. thanks for not just answer but you explain it. many thanks Jon Kloske,

Answer (score 2):

Use `order by desc limit 1` will the first element.

Example :

```
select*,sum(qty) as qtys from sometable GROUP BY name ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1
```

Since the price is determined by the latest entry, you just need to select by name = 'hot dog' for example, sum qty, order by id desc and limit  one result.

```
 select*,sum(qty)as qtys, price 
 fromsometable 
 where name ='Hot-Dog'  orderB by  id desc LIMIT 1
```

Hope this help.

Comment: i change my example, if you can help please help me.

Comment: @RickyJoe How is the latest price determined? latest entry? highest qty? date? ....

Comment: latest entry for same item,(name and taste) something like min(price) as prices or max(price) as prices. ORDER BY not worked

Answer (score 1):

You should do ORDER BY ascending or descending in your case descending.

```
"SELECT *,sum(qty) as qtys FROM sometable GROUP BY name ORDER BY price DESC"
```

There is more flexibility. Click here for more info http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: i change my example, if you can help please help me.

Comment: "...ORDER BY id DESC" this will select the highest id and then the second highest. If you only want one add LIMIT 1 this ONLY selects the one with highest id The link I gave can give you more info